# orphanRemoval does not work in OneToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, cascading-deletes

I have this two class in Java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserDb {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private BorrowerDb borrowerDb;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "borrower")
public class BorrowerDb {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @MapsId
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
   @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
   private UserDb user;
}
```

When I try to call "delete from user where id = ..." I receive the next error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`borrower`, CONSTRAINT `FK_7x1elq6p8384hj65g38w08jsm` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
```

But, why? I need that the child instance "Borrower" be deleted too.

Thanks!

Comment: You have mixed different techniques of one-to-one mapping: Sharing PK and Foreign Key.

Comment: Yes, is it a problem?

Comment: Could be. What is the purpose of `@MapsId` in your example? Are you sure you need bi-directional relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Start from the following basic example:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String parentName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
    private Child child;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String childName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "child")
    private Parent parent;

}
```

```java
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Integer> {
}

public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Integer> {
}
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
class Q78188732ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ChildRepository childRepository;

    @Test
    void persistAndRemoveParentTest() {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setChildName("child");

        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setParentName("parent");
        parent.setChild(child);

        parentRepository.save(parent);

        assertEquals(1, parentRepository.count());
        assertEquals(1, childRepository.count());

        Optional<Parent> persistedParent = parentRepository.findAll().stream().findFirst();

        assertTrue(persistedParent.isPresent());
        assertEquals("parent", persistedParent.get().getParentName());
        assertEquals("child", persistedParent.get().getChild().getChildName());

        Optional<Child> persistedChild = childRepository.findAll().stream().findFirst();

        assertTrue(persistedChild.isPresent());
        assertEquals("child", persistedChild.get().getChildName());
        assertEquals("parent", persistedChild.get().getParent().getParentName());

        parentRepository.deleteById(persistedParent.get().getId());

        assertEquals(0, parentRepository.count());
        assertEquals(0, childRepository.count());
    }

    @Test
    void persistAndRemoveChildTest() {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setChildName("child");

        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setParentName("parent");
        parent.setChild(child);

        parentRepository.save(parent);

        Optional<Parent> persistedParent = parentRepository.findAll().stream().findFirst();

        assertTrue(persistedParent.isPresent());

        persistedParent.get().setChild(null);
        parentRepository.save(persistedParent.get());

        assertEquals(0, childRepository.count());
        assertEquals(1, parentRepository.count());
    }

}
```